# How to defer wordpress block.json scripts?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm currently using @wordpress/scripts, but it puts scripts in HEAD section and doesn't defer them, which is often a bad bad thing. I was trying to defer them by doing something like:

```
// block.json
{
  "name": "myproject/counters",
  "title": "Counters",
  "description": "Blocco counters",
  "keywords": ["counters", "counter"],
  "style": [ "file:./counters.css", "counters_style" ],
  "script": [ "file:./counters.js", "counters_js" ],
  "align": "full"
}
```

and then:

```
if(!is_admin()) add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'lr_defer_scripts', 10, 3 );
function lr_defer_scripts( $tag, $handle, $src ) {

  $defer_scripts = array(
    'counters_js'
  );

  if(in_array($handle, $defer_scripts)){ return '<script src="' . $src . '" defer type="text/javascript"></script>' . "\n"; }
  return $tag;
}
```

But, turns out that this filter seems not to 'see' the counters_js $handle. It sees all the other scripts I usually use and defer, but not this one. Seems like passing the counters_js handle to block.json, it's not recognized by @wordpress/scripts.